# ReactJs: pass param in <Link> tag and open next page in new tab (Not working)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to send params through `state` to `<Link>` tag and trying to access that params in next component which will be opened in **new tab**. But while accessing params it says `undefined`.

The way I call Post detail screen and pass params through state:

```
<Link 
to={{
    pathname: `/post/${props.post.slug}`,
    state: {post: props.post}
}}></Link>
```

The way I am accessing params in `PostDetail.js` component.

```
const post = this.props.location.state.post;
```

It says `post` is `undefined`. So how can I achieve this?

If I try to this in single page flow, it will work(even if you refresh page). But when I try to open post detail in **new tab**, it gives error!

**Note**: ignore pathname and its value in above example!

Comment: How is the route defined for the path `/post/${props.post.slug}`? Did you use a `<Route ... component={PostDetail}>` component for it? Or did you wrap `PostDetail ` with the `withRouter` higher order component?

Comment: @Alserda This way <Route path="/post/:slug" component={PostDetail} />

Comment: anyone can help?